# find redirected domains with StormCrawler

Tags: stormcrawler

Our customer, give us a list of domains and ask to check redirect domains in that list. Domains are something similar this:
**[www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com),

domain.com,

subdomain1.domain.com,

subdomain1.subdomain2.domain.com,**

The StormCrawler only works with URLs. So if we want to feed domains list to the crawler, we need to do some pre-processing steps. For example, we may add http or https protocols at the begining of domains and add an slash at the end of domains.
In addition, the customer needs to know list of domains which redirects to a different domain. For example, if **[www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com)** redirected to **[www.domain2.com](http://www.domain2.com)**, we need to report that. How can I do that in the StormCrawler project?

Answer (score 1):

Converting domain names into URLs is best done when putting the domains either into the seed list or with state "discovered" into the status index. After some time when the URLs are fetched (use a depth filter to limit the depth to the seeds only): look up the URLs in the status index and report all URLs with a metadata field "_redirTo" pointing to a different domain.